# How to combine three many to many relationship results in a single collection in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship between the following:

actor <-> theater_play, actor <-> musical, actor <-> ballet_play

How can I make a single array to display all the results from these relationships in Laravel?

I have now:

`$actor->theaterPlays`, `$actor->musicals`, `$actor->balletPlays`

And I need to have something like this:

`$actor->allPerformances`

EDIT:

And I have to order theym by name, or by date of the performance etc.

Comment: Did you attempt to eager-load multiple relationship? e.g `$performances = App\Actor::with(['theaterPlays', 'musicals', 'balletPlays'])->get();` ?

Comment: Yes, but can't access them from the "relationship". Is there a way to do it from the actor model?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, however you should be able to create a new [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) within your `Actor` model which is responsible for merging all types together:

```
public function getAllPerformancesAttribute()
{
    return $this->theaterPlays()
        ->get()
        ->merge($this->musicals()->get())
        ->merge($this->balletPlays()->get())
        ->all();
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! With this I can order them by create date, or date of the play or name or what I want, right?

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab Not with normal eloquent query methods no. You first will need to take away the `->all()` so an array is not returned. Secondly, you will need to use collection methods. However with such needs I wouldnt say this is the best solution.

Comment: @thisskelvin thank you, I will experiment more and try to think of a way to make this happen. :)